# What is the meaning of 'successive dynasties'?

Tags: meaning, word-usage, phrases, expressions, meaning-in-context

I know it means one after another, but dynasty means a series of rulers or leaders who are all from the same family.

how could one family have two dynasty?

I mean, it is same dynasty then why they called it successive???[image: n]

Comment: If you go back far enough, we’re all related. You can have a different dynasty when there is enough of a change, such as (or even typically?) non-hereditary succession.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> how could one family have two dynasty?

You're misinterpreting the passage.

The Kushans were a culture/society that formed an empire in India. It says that there were *two families* that formed two separate ruling *dynasties*. The first was the Kadphises and the second was the Kanishka. The Kanishka directly followed on from the Kadphises, therefore they are *successive dynasties*.

Comment: can you also give hypothetical example ?

Comment: I'm not sure how a hypotheticial example would be of benefit given that this is a fairly concrete example of successive dynasties in the real world.

Comment: means they are from different family? different blood relationship ?

Comment: Yes, there were two different families (refered to as houses in the text) that formed two different dynasties within the Kushan empire.

Comment: they may have fought with each other, am i right?

Comment: They might have fought each other but there's nothing in the provided text to suggest that they did.

Comment: In English history, a new dynasty was considered to start when the new king was only distantly related to the previous monarch, either because there was no direct heir (Elizabeth I) or when a weak king was overthrown.